# Extend HTML file with script and override/extend some section tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing, html-parser

There is open source (client side) which I can use to extend HTML,
for example I need to add scripts to it or change some of the src values and add additional tags, etc.

I found the following: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-extend

but I'm not sure if I can use it in the **client** (we don't use gulp in our project) By client I mean for example to use it in **jsFiddle**.

The input should be HTML content with some object/json with the new content and the output should be extended HTML.

If there is no open source , and I need to develop it myself, is there is some guide line I should follow from good design aspects?

**UPDATE:**

For example if I've the following HTML doc as JS input variable

***THIS IS THE INPUT WHICH I GOT AS STRING***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>td</title>

        <script id="test-ui-bootstrap"
            src="resources/test-ui-core.js"
            data-test-ui-libs="test.m"
            data-test-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-test-ui-resourceroots='{"tdrun": "./"}'>
        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <script>
            test.ui.get().attachInit(function() {
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body class="testUiBody" id="content">
    </body>

</html>
```

For example I need the following:

## 1.

I want to add additional script (e.g. with alert inside) after

```
<script id="test-ui-bootstrap" ....
```

if there is in the file script with id **"test-ui-bootstrap"**

I want to add immediately after this script another script e.g.

```
script with alert inside
```

## 2.

To add additional property inside the first script(with id id="test-ui-bootstrap")  after the last script...

```
data-test-ui-libs="test.m"
```

To add

```
data-test-ui-libs123 ="test.bbb"
```

## 3.

If I want to modify the value of existing property e.g. change

```
src="resources/test-ui-core.js"
```

to

```
src="resources/aaaa/test-ui-core.js"
```

**I got string with HTML and I need to create new string with the modified HTML** I can I do it right with nice way?

UPDATE 2

***THIS IS THE OUTPUT AFTER THE HTML WAS CHANGED***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta charset="UTF-8">

            <title>td</title>

            <script id="test-ui-bootstrap"
                src="resources/aaaa/test-ui-core.js"
                data-test-ui-libs="test.m"
                data-test-ui-libs123 ="test.bbb"
                data-test-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
                data-test-ui-resourceroots='{"tdrun": "./"}'>
            </script>
            <script>
               alert("test)
            </script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

            <script>
                test.ui.get().attachInit(function() {
                });
            </script>
        </head>

        <body class="testUiBody" id="content">
        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Can you break your question down to a minimal example of what you like to do, cause so far it just sounds normal html editting to me (source code view?). In any case, I think the question the way it is now, is also to broad to give a good answer to

Comment: @Icepickle - please see my update, is it OK?

Comment: Yeah, so you want to parse the text and extend it as certain points? It's not something when it's running live inside the browser, it's just manipulation of a text input? I'm not sure of the second point, if you add the same data name to a script element, the browser engine wouldn't really now how to handle that, maybe you want to extend manipulate the original tag?

Comment: @Icepickle - yes this is what I want...no Its not running live...sorry for the second point lets say I need to change/add key (I'll update my post) Thanks!

Comment: I think what you need is DOMParser, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser. You can use the DOM API to update it.

Comment: @Mark So, you do not award your a bounty?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a sandboxed element outside of the DOM, then insert your HTML  into it.

```
var sandbox = document.createElement('div');
sandbox.innerHTML = yourHTMLString;
```

The browser will parse your HTML, then you'll be able to traverse/modify it with the DOM APIs.

You can use it to find elements and add attributes.

```
var script = sandbox.querySelectorAll('#test-ui-bootstrap');
script.setAttribute('data-test-ui-libs', 'test.m');
script.setAttribute('src', 'resources/aaaa/test-ui-core.js');
```

Or insert new elements after existing ones.

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.innerText = 'your script contents';
script.parentNode.insertBefore(newScript, script.nextSibling);
```

As soon as you're ready to work with it as a string again, you can read it out as a property.

```
var html = sandbox.innerHTML;
```

**Note**. Different browsers handle the `innerHTML` mechanism differently and you might find that they strip the `<body>` and `<head>` tags when you insert your HTML into your sandbox.

If this is the case then you can workaround it with a hack.

```
var escapedTags = yourHTMLString
  .replace(/body/ig, 'body$')
  .replace(/head/ig, 'head$')

// now the browser won't recognize the tags
// and therefore won't strip them out.
sandbox.innerHTML = escapedTags;

// do some work
// ...

// don't forget to unescape them!
var unescapedTags = sandbox.innerHTML
  .replace(/body\$/g, 'body')
  .replace(/head\$/g, 'head');
```

This makes use of the fact that the browser won't understand what a `<body$>` or a `<head$>` tag is, so it just leaves in intact.

Comment: Thanks , Can you please provide example in jsFiddle for the question that I write?

Comment: @Mark, paste your HTML into the input textarea to test it out.

Comment: Thanks! but I try it and it doesnt work for me, please see update 2 with the output that I want to get,I need to pass html as string and return extended html as string

Comment: Thanks Dan but still doesntwork for me How can I got the updated version? just f5 doest work.another question can you please provide some generic solution , in your solution if for example the html will not have  attr-data-test-ui-libs you will get exception I,my need is a bit more complicated :) I want to define some object with properties which you can put there attr to query and new script and where is the place to put it , I need some generic solution which is not related to specific property or script, the use can define json/object with the needs and I want to read it and change the html

Comment: I'm using the same HTML as you are. What's wrong for you?

There's no way to create a generic solution for such a specific problem. The DOM API is already a domain specific language for working with manipulating DOM nodes, which is exactly what you want to do. If you can write the DOM manipulation code you need to get from A to B then I'll try and derive a more generic form.

Comment: HI Dan, 1. if some of the entry are missing I got error(TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of undefined) , how it can be more stable ?(for example if attr-data-test-ui-libs doesnt exist...)   2. regard the script with the alert if I want to put it in other place how should I handle it in generic way, Thank you!

Comment: __1__ - Check whether the element is `null`/`undefined` before calling `setAttribute`.
__2__ - Rather than inserting it before the `script.nextSibling` element, insert it before the element you want it to go before instead.

Comment: Your solution replaces every word "body" and "head" to body$ and head$. It does not have to be inside <> brackets. Furthermore, you are replacing &quot; everywhere instead of replacing it only inside data attributes. Finally, you are adding a doctype no matter if there was one before. Your solution would therefore not work if you have only a fragment/snippet of an HTML page. The rest is fine, therefore no downvote.

Comment: The answer only demonstrates the concept, it's not meant to be borrowed line for line. It's not clear what the asker actually wants to achieve, so these are more or less just demonstrations of techniques they could use.

Answer (score 0):

**INITIAL (Node.js)**

I understand your question as follows: You want to parse a HTML string in a Node.js environment (you mentioned Gulp), extend it and get the resulting string back.

First, you need to parse the string into a structure, on which you can make queries. There are several libraries available to achieve this. [Cheerio.js](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) was recommended and explained in a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19934759/3233827). Other solutions are also explaind [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7373003/3233827). The library provides you then an interface to the DOM of your HTML code. In the example of Cheerio.js, you can access the DOM similarly as in jQuery. The official example of their GitHub page is depicted below. In a similar manner, you can do your logic by selecting the elements and add your content (modify it, etc.). By calling the `$.html()` function, you get the modified structure back.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>');

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
$('h2').addClass('welcome');

$.html();

// => returns '<h2 class="title welcome">Hello there!</h2>'
```

If you want to use this logic in a Gulp build process, you need to wrap it into a Gulp plugin with Cheerio.js as a dependency. On this [official GitHub readme file of Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/README.md) it is explained in detail how you can create a Gulp plugin.

**EDIT (Browser)**

According to your edited question, I'll add this section about editing the HTML in the browser.

It is very convenient to use jQuery to modify a DOM in the browser. You can also modify a virtual DOM with jQuery. To do that, you just need to create the element but not append it to the real DOM. Unfortunately, the browser acts special when it comes to the following tags: `<html>`, `<body>`, `<head>` and `<!DOCTYPE html>`. As a workaround, you can just edit those tags with a regular expression and rename them to something like `<body_temp>` and so on. You need to have a good regular expression to only match tags and not content like `class="testUiBody"` which does also contain the word `body`. The special behavior is decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10060869/3233827) in detail.

The following code makes all the desired changes in the HTML. You can test it in an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6roLps95/5/). Just click the Submit button and you can see the changes. The upper `textarea` acts as HTML input and the lower one as HTML output.

```
var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta.....";

// replace html, head and body tag with html_temp, head_temp and body_temp
html = html.replace(/<!DOCTYPE HTML>/i, '<doctype></doctype>');
html = html.replace(/(<\/?(?:html)|<\/?(?:head)|<\/?(?:body))/ig, '$1_temp');

// wrap the dom into a <container>: the html() function returns only the contents of an element
html = "<container>"+html+"</container>"; 

// parse the HTML
var element = $(html);

// do your calculations on the parsed html
$("<script>alert(\"test\");<\/script>").insertAfter(element.find('#test-ui-bootstrap'));
element.find("#test-ui-bootstrap").attr('data-test-ui-libs123', "test.bbb");
element.find("#test-ui-bootstrap").attr('src', 'resources/aaaa/test-ui-core.js');

// reset the initial changes (_temp)
var extended_html = element.html();
extended_html = extended_html.replace(/<doctype><\/doctype>/, '<!DOCTYPE HTML>');
extended_html = extended_html.replace(/(<\/?html)_temp/ig, '$1');
extended_html = extended_html.replace(/(<\/?head)_temp/ig, '$1');
extended_html = extended_html.replace(/(<\/?body)_temp/ig, '$1');

// replace all &quot; inside data-something=""
while(extended_html.match(/(<.*?\sdata.*?=".*?)(&quot;)(.*?".*?>)/g)) {
  extended_html = extended_html.replace(/(<.*?\sdata.*?=".*?)(&quot;)(.*?".*?>)/g, "$1'$3");
}

// => extended_html contains now your edited HTML
```

Comment: HI, This is almost what I need , I need to parse the string (with html content) to HTML which I can query from,but I need it in client side for example in jsFiddle , can you please provide example how it can be done in jsFiddle with the HTML I put in the question,for example to add script after the first script ...I need to get some html as string and provide modified html after I modified it with the requirement I put in the question....Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Thanks but not sure If I got your answer... I need as your suggestion a way to parse this html string and query it and provide new extended html , your fiddle is too basic and doesn't answer my requirements ...I need the html that I put as input and the output should be the extended html...Thanks again

Comment: please see my updated question maybe its more clear now...Thanks!

Comment: I updated the code and the fiddle to match your requirements. You can now directly convert your HTML code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've 3 questions, 1 can you please elaborate on " the browser acts special when it comes to the following tags:" 2. Does your code is secured ? 3. what if I dont find specific element/ attr /script (the example is specific...) how should it be handled safe?

Comment: 1. The browser strips away those tags and returns only the contents of it. You can see this behavior when commenting out line 8 in the JSFiddle (replacement of body, etc. with body_temp, etc.). 2. What do you mean with "secured"? The browser engine is used to parse the HTML. This means, it depends on the browser, how the result looks like. My solution replaces the word "body" only if it follows a `<` to prevent replacements like "testUiBody". If you don't have a tag named like `<body_temp>`, etc. on another place in your code, then it is save.

Comment: If you want to parse the HTML independently of the browser engine, you need a library like the one I proposed first (Cheerio.js), which parses the HTML in its own way. This way, it most probably will also work in Internet Explorer (you need to check the requirements of this Node.js module). And to 3.: I used standard jQuery for the replacements. If jQuery cannot find an element, it just doesn't do anything. It is on you to find the best error handling. You can check, if an element is found by using the `length` attribute: `if($('#element').length) { // it was found; } else { // not found; }`

Comment: jQuery is the most common solution to edit an HTML DOM. It is very widely used and makes it very simple to edit attributes and content of an HTML element. You can also easily traverse through the DOM. Please refer to the official reference guide of jQuery to get more information: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: HI This is my last question on this topic :)  , assume that I need to get all the changes (like the question , the script/new property etc) to a function to handle (like your code is doing) it how you would write it ,lets assume that your code is a function and all the changes should become as parameters to this function(the new script can be string and the property can be a key value ) can you update your JsFiddle,Thanks a lot I very like your answer :)

Comment: It depends on your needs: In the jsFiddle, the code is already wrapped in a function, which reads in the textarea, parses it, edits it and converts it back to HTML. I would however write a function which contains all the code until the parsing and return the parsed HTML element. You can then modify it depending on your needs. Then, in another function, the element is converted back to plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

### `DOMParser` and `XMLSerializer`.

The most important thing is; this is not a sandbox. It only uses a parser & serializer; and therefore it will not execute the scripts within the input; until you inject the output into an actual DOM.

```js
// HTML string to be modified
var strHTML = '<html>...</html>'; // your HTML
// We'll parse this string into DOM in memory.
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = parser.parseFromString(strHTML, 'text/html'),
    // in this example, we'll get the script elements and change/set 
    // some attributes of the first and the content of the second
    scripts = doc.getElementsByTagName('script');
scripts[0].setAttribute('data-test-ui-libs123', 'test.bbb');
scripts[0].setAttribute('src', 'resources/aaaa/test-ui-core.js');
scripts[1].innerHTML = 'alert("test")';
// now that we've modified the HTML, we can serialize it into string
var serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
    outputHTML = serializer.serializeToString(doc);
```

- [**Example Pen**](http://codepen.io/onury/full/ONRjmB/).
- [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) on MDN.
- [**Browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xml-serializer): IE10+ and modern browsers.

### `jQuery.parseHTML()`

The `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()` API also does not execute scripts or fetch resources via HTTP (such as videos, images, etc). This is the approach used by [`jQuery.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) method. See [source here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.parseHTML).

From jQuery docs; security considerations:

> Most jQuery APIs that accept HTML strings will run scripts that are included in the HTML. jQuery.parseHTML does not run scripts in the parsed HTML unless keepScripts is explicitly true. However, it is still possible in most environments to execute scripts indirectly, for example via the  attribute. The caller should be aware of this and guard against it by cleaning or escaping any untrusted inputs from sources such as the URL or cookies. For future compatibility, callers should not depend on the ability to run any script content when keepScripts is unspecified or false.

Comment: Thanks but your code handle just the first question, how should I handle the question 2&3 in generic way? Thank you!

Comment: That should be obvious. You use the DOM APIs such as `element.setAttribute()` to set/change an attribute. See the updated code and example pen.

Comment: Thanks I checking it , one question about security, is your solution is a bit risky ? where should I Put the keepScripts ?