# Extract DOM Node from HTML String, Result as HTML String

Tags: jquery

Given

```
var html = "<html><body><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Ciao!</p></body></html>";
```

I would like to extract the inner HTML of the `body` tag (`<p>Hello, World!</p><p>Ciao!</p>`).

`.find()` finds the `body` DOM node

```
var body = $(html).find("body");
```

but I cannot find a means to get the inner HTML of that node.  I tried:

```
var text = body.text(); //  returns ""
var var = body.var(); // returns undefined
```

How can I get a string representation of the `<body>` tag's inner HTML?

Comment: `$(html).find("body").html();` ?

Comment: @aroth: That is also `undefined`.

Comment: Then I believe this is the explanation for why it is not working:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488839/does-jquery-strip-some-html-elements-from-a-string-when-using-html.  Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aNh6a/); in Chrome everything is stripped except the two `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will strip the `html` and `body` tags out when you wrap the string in `$()`.

Therefore you can do this:

```
var str=$('<div>').append($(html)).html()
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LxdrM/

Comment: Correct, except that it doesn't appear to be jQuery that is doing it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488839/does-jquery-strip-some-html-elements-from-a-string-when-using-html

Answer (score 1):

You could use substring, get the index of  and the index of  and make a substring with what is inside.

```
var bot = html.indexOf("<body>");
var top= html.indexOf("</body>");
var body=html.substring(bot,top);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `body[0].innerHTML()`

Comment: var body = $(html).find("body"); will return an array of elements. Use body[0] to get the element and call the innerHTML function on it.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to show the string representation, it will be better to keep the html in a `div` element (or any other element inside the body tag) instead of `body` tag itself. For string representation, use `TextArea` which is what also SO is using.

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKcE3/)**

```
$(function(){
   var body = $('html').find('div'); 
   var text = body.html(); 
   $("#textArea").val(text);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
     <body>
        <div><p>Hello, World!</p>
             <p>Ciao!</p>
        </div>
        <textarea id="textArea" name="post-text" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="101">
        </textarea>
     </body>    
 </html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the HTML fragment.  It does not have a single tag that contains the rest of the tags inside the body.