# Bootstrap popover data from another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Instead of the data being hardcoded, I want it to retrieve it from a html file, a template if you will. How can I do this? Let's say I have another html file with a `<h1>` and a `<body>`, and the popover should get the data from it (header/body of the popover)

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Help" data-toggle="popover"  data-content="423241421453453"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="font-size: 20px; padding-top:5px"></span></button>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function popover() {
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have a template like this :

```html
<h1>header</h1>
<body>this is a test</body>
```

Then add the template filename as a `data-templatefile` attribute to your button markup :

```html
<button type="button" data-templatefile="template.html" class="btn btn-default" title="Help" data-toggle="popover"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="font-size: 20px; padding-top:5px"></span></button>
```

Then initialise the popover like this :

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html : true,
    content : function() {
        return loadContent($(this).data('templatefile'))
    }
});
```

This was straigt forward. The `loadContent()` needs to be more tricky. If you use jQuery to parse the content you will see that the `<body>` tag is stripped out. This is [the browser doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2488839/1407478), not jQuery. But you can use a `DOMParser` instead to extract exactly those tags you want to use in the popover :

```js
function loadContent(templateFile) {
    return $('<div>').load(templateFile, function(html) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
        return doc.querySelector('h1').outerHTML + doc.querySelector('body').outerHTML;
    })
}
```

The result will look like this :
[image]

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/9pHmKBvhxMOdGjCHz2OG?p=preview**

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't get it to work, could you make it in a plunker or something please?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have my lunch break and I'll be awaiting your response.

Comment: @BudaCristian - see update, works right away - perhaps you have some other script errors preventing the code from being executed?

Comment: well this worked, but how would I do it if I want to get a template.html from a specific path ?

Comment: @BudaCristian -???, you just specify the path too `data-templatefile="somedir/another/div/template.html"` ... `data-templatefile="../templates/template.html"` etc

Comment: This is very very... and I mean, *very* useful even in a case you'd like to render popovers with an external `div`. Thank you very much.