# HTML div embedded in bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a popover (bootstrap). The layout of the popover needs to be defined in another html file. I am unable to link to the html file from my popover.

Here is my popover code:

```
> <div ng-class="'tile thumbnail  pull-left activity-tile '+
> activityTypeStyle">
>     <div>
>         <div class="activity-icon">
>             <div ng-class="activityTileIcon">
>                 <i></i>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <div class="activity-detail">
>             <div class="link"><a ng-click="navigate()" ng-prevent-drag >{{selection.activityName}}</a></div>
>             <div class="detail" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="bottom"
> data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"
> popover="{{selection.details}}">{{selection.details}}</div>
>         </div>
>         <div class="activity-lock" ng-show="!manualTask"><i class="fa fa-lock"  title="Automated Task"></i></div>
>     </div>
> </div>
```

'pendingApprovalPopup.html' is the layout of the popover.

Layout file is as follows:

```
<html>
>     <head>
>         <h1>header</h1>
> 
> 
> </head>
>     <body>this is a test</body> 
> </html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set data-content using HTML file, you have to use the JAVASCRIPT.

Set data-content initially blank.

Please go through below mentioned link: Little bit modification and solution is there

[Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13202762/4308418)

Comment: It doesn't work. I am not able to render the layout. While inspecting the element, I see that the tags are not being rendered. I am going to edit my question to include more detail. Hope you could help me out then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the attribute called data-templatefile="" then initialise it with jQuery

Here is a link you can use :)

[Bootstrap popover data from another HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146660/bootstrap-popover-data-from-another-html-file)

Comment: It doesn't work. I am not able to render the layout. While inspecting the element, I see that the tags are not being rendered. I am going to edit my question to include more detail. Hope you could help me out then.