# Convert jQuery element to html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This JS code tries to modify the raw html. It does that by converting the html to jQuery element, does the modifications on the jQuery element then the part which is not working is converting back to raw html string.

Since `.html()` will not work with xml as indicated in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
How can it convert the jQuery back to raw html string? Thanks

```js
let jQ = $($.parseHTML(raw_html));
//modify jQ to heart content
console.log(jQ.html()); //<-- undefined
```

The raw_html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
//...

</html>
```

**edit**
Output of `console.log($.parseHTML(raw_html));`
[image]

Comment: html() works with xml. JQuery said so only because to play safe.

Comment: What does `$.parseHTML(raw-html)` return? Is that defined, note that `raw-html` isn't a proper variable name because of the subtraction.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek `console.log($.parseHTML(raw_html));`returns an object, I am posting its image now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do
`var a = $('<div>').append(raw_html);`

//do modifications to variable `a`

`$(a).html()` will display the correct html

NOTE this will strip head and other tags as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488839/does-jquery-strip-some-html-elements-from-a-string-when-using-html)

heres a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Aa9x871vdrAxL5ynP5t6?p=info)