# jQuery selector is overlooking elements from a separate context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm making an ajax request to a page on my site with this element as a direct child of the body tag:

```
<div class="container" id="wantme"><div class="content"></div></div>
```

There's only one `.container`, and I want to grab its ID which I don't know.

As far as I can tell, this code should do what I want:

```
$.get('/page', function(data) {
    id = $('.container', data).attr('id');
});
```

But the `.container` selector fails to find anything.

I did find these two workarounds. I can find `.content`, and I can climb up the tree like this:

```
id = $('.content', data).parent().attr('id');
```

But I can't leap directly there.

I found this workaround elsewhere on StackOverflow that works:

```
html = $('<div></div>').html(data);
id = html.find('.container').attr('id');
```

But why is it that the seemingly obvious answer doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The only place I use .find() it actually works here. The first bit of code is broken, the second two are workarounds I've found that work.

Comment: What about `$(data).find(".container").attr("id");` ?

Comment: @31piy Solid idea, sadly it still behaves the same way.

Comment: @TylerRoper It shows the same wacky behavior. I've made a jsfiddle to hopefully make it a little easier to play around with for anyone who wants to. https://jsfiddle.net/8vcu4Lo1/

Comment: Well that JSFiddle cleared up the answer for me. I'll post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:** I'll leave my original answer at the bottom, however I'm concerned it may misbehave depending on browser. jQuery's `.html()` makes use of Javascript's `innerHTML` -  some browsers choose to strip `<head>` and `<body>` tags when using `innerHTML`, whereas others do not.

The safest method to achieve what you're after may still be the workaround you mentioned, like so:

```js
var data = '<!doctype html><html><body><div class="container" id="findme"><div class="content"></div></div></body></html>';

var $container = $("<div />").html(data).find(".container");
var id = $container.attr("id");

console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

More information as to the browser-related issues [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488839/does-jquery-strip-some-html-elements-from-a-string-when-using-html).

---

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

When you pass HTML to a jQuery element, it will ignore the `<body>` tags, as well as anything *outside* of them. Given the data string in your JSFiddle, `$(data)` will create something that looks like this:

```
<div class="container" id="findme">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the HTML above, your `.container` isn't *inside* of `$(data)` - it **is** `$(data)`.

Because `$(data)` is representing your `.container` element, you should just be able to do `$(data).attr("id")` to retrieve what you're after.

```js
var data = '<!doctype html><html><body><div class="container" id="findme"><div class="content"></div></div></body></html>';
var id = $(data).attr('id');
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fantastic, that was it! Excellent work! Side questions, what happens when there are multiple top level elements (My full page does have a sibling or two for .container), and is there any way to avoid this stripdown?

Comment: `$(data)` will correspond to the first top-level element, ignoring siblings after it. Regarding you second point, take a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488839/does-jquery-strip-some-html-elements-from-a-string-when-using-html) - it may be helpful. Given the information included within, I believe your `$(<div></div>")` workaround may actually be safer. Though, it could be shortened to just `$("<div />")`.

Comment: @Different55 Upon investigation I've edited my answer. I think that my previous answer will not work across all browsers. Not only will the suggested work around be cross-browser compatible, but I think it will solve your sibling issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the ID from `$('.container', data).attr('id');` is because you are setting the value of the second parameter. What you want to do is this: `$('.container ' + data).attr('id');`.

Update:
If data is a string then you should convert it into a DOM element: `$('.container', $(data)).attr('id');`

Comment: I'm not quite sure that makes sense in this context. `data` is a string containing a full HTML document. I have it set as a second parameter so that it's interpreted as a document all its own, and so that the selector is executed in that context. See this bit of the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). Appending the HTML string to the selector ends in `".container <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>..."` and spits out a syntax error.